# get difference of non-na dates based on condition

Tags: r, date, if-statement, data-manipulation

Logic I am trying to build is as below

I have 4 dates columns in my table date,date1,date2,date3

if date & date1 is non-null(not blank), x=date-date1
else date & date2 is non-null, x= date-date2
else date &date3 are non-null, x = date-date3 .. where x is metric I am trying to derive.

I have tested below code in jupyter and it works fine as I was able to validate.

```
df$ttf <- ifelse((!is.na(df$date) & !is.na(df$date1)), df$ttf <- mondf(df$date1,df$date),
                 ifelse((!is.na(df$date) & !is.na(df$date2)), df$ttf <- mondf(df$date2,df$date),
                        ifelse((!is.na(df$date) & !is.na(df$date3)), df$ttf <- mondf(df$date3,df$date),
                               NA)))
```

however when I am running this job in GCP , I am getting below error

```
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if it brings you forward. The `df$ttf <-`  within the `ifelse` should be deleted.

```
df <- transform(df, ttf=ifelse(!is.na(date) & !is.na(date1), date1 - date, 
                              ifelse(!is.na(date) & !is.na(date2), date2 - date, 
                                     ifelse(!is.na(date) & !is.na(date3), date3 - date, 
                                            NA))))
df
#         date      date1      date2      date3 ttf
# 1 2021-01-01 2021-03-12 2021-05-21 2021-07-30  70
# 2 2021-01-15 2021-03-26 2021-06-04 2021-08-13  70
# 3 2021-01-29 2021-04-09 2021-06-18 2021-08-27  70
# 4 2021-02-12 2021-04-23 2021-07-02 2021-09-10  70
# 5 2021-02-26 2021-05-07 2021-07-16 2021-09-24  70
# 6 2021-03-12 2021-05-21 2021-07-30 2021-10-08  70
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18628, 18642, 18656, 18670, 
18684, 18698), class = "Date"), date1 = structure(c(18698, 18712, 
18726, 18740, 18754, 18768), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(18768, 
18782, 18796, 18810, 18824, 18838), class = "Date"), date3 = structure(c(18838, 
18852, 18866, 18880, 18894, 18908), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: is it transform? also can I use mondf function in the same to get the date diff.?

Comment: @AshishPandey Yess sorry the typo!